# How to read parameters from URL that ends with .jpg

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, optimization

I have a script called `image.php` that does some image manipulation like resizing and optimization. I already wrote `.htaccess` to omit the `.php` at the end and now I have something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/images/imageFolderPath/myImage.jpg?width=100&keep_aspect=1&quality=80
```

where the parameters were supposed to be passed to `images.php` and be used to manipulate `imageFolderPath/myImage.jpg`.

My problem is I don't know how to write .htaccess that would read the `imageFolderPath/myImage.jpg` as a parameter and also pass along other parameters if exist.

I got the whole idea from AirBnB website, how they manipulate their images like this

https://a1.muscache.com/ic/discover/94?interpolation=lanczos-none&output-format=jpg&output-quality=70&v=33b4f2&downsize=326px:326px

This is my .htaccess so far:

```
#RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ images.php?image_path=$1.$2 [L,QSA,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: `images` is not a folder, the original URL is `http://www.example.com/images.php/imageFolderPath/myImage.jpg?width=100&keep_aspect=1&quality=80`. Also I can't determine how many parameters would be passed, if any of them is not set, the default value would be used

Comment: Yes it is, and I want to extract `imageFolderPath/myImage.jpg` and any other parameter after `?`

Comment: It doesn't work, please explain to me how the above rules work, maybe I can figure out what I'm missing out. there are 4 parts in the URL: The base url `http://www.example.com`, the php script `images.php` rewritten as `images`, the path to the image `imageFolderPath/myImage.jpg` and the parameters `width=100&keep_as‌​pect=1&quality=80`.

Comment: Yes I want the URL to be treated that way, that's all the rules I have currently.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect this `localhost/images/imageFolderPath/myImage.jpg?width=100&keep_aspect=1&quality=80‌​` to `localhost/images.php?image_path=imageFolderPath/myImage.jpg&width=100&keep_aspect=1&qualit‌​y=80`. I believe this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyse the request URI in your php using:

```
$_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];
```

It will contain information about the path requested by the user, it should include also the filename.